# Error sintaxis java

Tags: java, mysql

Buenas,

Tengo el siguiente código pero no se ejecuta a partir de crear la tabla en la base de datos. Imagino que será un error de sintaxis en el `INSERT` o en el `UPDATE`:

```
public class Conectate {
private String driver ="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
private String cadenaConexion ="jdbc:mysql://localhost/XboxOne";
private String pass = "";
private String usuario = "root";
public Connection con;

public Conectate(Map<String,  Map<String, Item>> gamesByCountry, Map<String, String> codesByTitle,Map<String, String> countries) {
    try {
        Class.forName(driver);
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(cadenaConexion, usuario, pass);
        System.out.println("¡Conectado!");


        //CREAMOS LA TABLA
        Statement st = con.createStatement();

        st.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS info_XboxOne (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY(id), "
                + "Juego_vinculado VARCHAR(500), Juego VARCHAR(500), Tipologia VARCHAR (500), Pertenece VARCHAR (500), "
                + "Nota VARCHAR (10), Descripcion_Ingles TEXT(4000), Descripcion_Castellano TEXT(4000), Pegi VARCHAR(10), Descripcion_Pegi VARCHAR(200),"
                + "Lanzamiento VARCHAR (50))");

        System.out.println( "Tabla creada!");



        for (String titulo : codesByTitle.keySet()) {     

            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM info_XboxOne WHERE juego = " + titulo);

            if (!rs.next()) { //si se cumple esta condicción significa que el juego no está incluido, con lo que lo metemos
                PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO info_XboxOne (Juego, Tipologia, Pertenece, "
                + "Nota, Descripcion_Ingles, Descripcion_Castellano, Pegi, Descripcion_Pegi, Lanzamiento"
                + ") VALUES (?,?,?,?"
                + ",?,?,?,?,?"
                + ")");

                String code = codesByTitle.get(titulo);

                for (String country : countries.keySet()) {
            Item game = gamesByCountry.get(country).get(code);

                            if (country.equals("Estados Unidos")) {                                  
                                ps.setString(1,titulo);
                            }

            if (game != null) {

                                    if (country.equals("Estados Unidos")) {
                                        ps.setString(2,game.getValues().get(Constants.TIPOLOGIA));
                                        ps.setString(3,game.getValues().get(Constants.PERTENECE));                                            
                                        ps.setString(4,game.getValues().get(Constants.NOTA));
                                        ps.setString(9,game.getValues().get(Constants.FECHA));
                                        ps.setString(5,game.getValues().get(Constants.DESCRIPCION_INGLES));
                                    }

                                    if (country.equals("España")) {
                                        ps.setString(6,game.getValues().get(Constants.DESCRIPCION_CASTELLANO));
                                        ps.setString(7,game.getValues().get(Constants.PEGI));
                                        ps.setString(8,game.getValues().get(Constants.DESCRIPCION_PEGI));
                                    }

            }
                }
                ps.executeUpdate();
            } else { //El juego existe, con lo que actualizamos los datos.
                String query = "UPDATE info_XboxOne SET Tipologia = ?, Pertenece = ?, "
                + "Nota = ?, Descripcion_Ingles = ?, Descripcion_Castellano = ?, "
                + "Pegi = ?, Descripcion_Pegi = ?, Lanzamiento = ? WHERE juego = " + titulo;
                PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);

                String code = codesByTitle.get(titulo);
                for (String country : countries.keySet()) {
        Item game = gamesByCountry.get(country).get(code);

                    if (country.equals("Estados Unidos")) {                                  
                        ps.setString(1,titulo);
                    }

        if (game != null) {

                       if (country.equals("Estados Unidos")) {
                            ps.setString(2,game.getValues().get(Constants.TIPOLOGIA));
                            ps.setString(3,game.getValues().get(Constants.PERTENECE));                                            
                            ps.setString(4,game.getValues().get(Constants.NOTA));
                            ps.setString(9,game.getValues().get(Constants.FECHA));
                            ps.setString(5,game.getValues().get(Constants.DESCRIPCION_INGLES));
                        }

                        if (country.equals("España")) {
                            ps.setString(6,game.getValues().get(Constants.DESCRIPCION_CASTELLANO));
                            ps.setString(7,game.getValues().get(Constants.PEGI));
                            ps.setString(8,game.getValues().get(Constants.DESCRIPCION_PEGI));
                        }

        }
                }
                ps.executeUpdate();
            }                                  

        }




    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se ha podido establecer la conexión con la DB" + e);
    }

}

public String ConvertirObjectToString(Object Obj) {
String Str="";
if(Obj!=null){
    Str = Obj.toString();
}
return Str;
}


}
```

El error que me da es:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Pero que tipo de excepción te lanza? Se me ocurren 2 cosas, si no te conecta con la base de datos podría faltarte indicar el puerto en la URL de la base de datos. Y si es un error de sintaxis, en las sentencias Insert o Update debes finalizarlas con `;`

Comment: Este es el error que me lanza: https://s2.postimg.org/nhjtznc61/Captura_de_pantalla_2017_02_25_a_las_16_15_24.png

Comment: A la base de datos se conecta, de hecho crea la tabla, pero no me introduce los datos.

Answer (score 2):

Estas tapando informaciónes a la excepción, así es difícil de ver en que consulta queda el error.

Cambia tu código de:

```
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se ha podido establecer la conexión con la DB" + e);
    }
```

a

```
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se ha podido establecer la conexión con la DB" + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

La excepción completa te va dar el numero de línea donde se hace la consulta que no te funciona.

Revisando la sintaxis de tu SQL, todo esta bien hasta que agregas el valor. El error de la sintaxis se produce porque comparas un campo con un dato literal sin ponerlo entre comillas, **podrías** construir tu SQL por ejemplo como:

```
String sql = String.format("SELECT * FROM info_XboxOne WHERE juego = '%s' ",titulo);
```

**Sin embargo**, este manera te hace **vulnerable** a inyección de SQL, porque no te proteja a datos que contienen "'", así deberías preferir lo que ya hiciste en otras partes y usar un "prepared statement":

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.preparedStatement("SELECT * FROM info_XboxOne WHERE juego = ?");
ps.setString(1,titulo);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

Como usas puros campos tipo `String`, para facilitarte tu trabajo en el caso que usas muchas consultas, puedes declararte un método para evitar de repetir código:

```
public ResultSet execPreparedQuery(Connection con, String query, String... data){
    PreparedStatement ps = con.preparedStatement(query);
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length, i++){
        ps.setString(i+1, data[i]);
    }
    return ps.executeQuery();
}
```

Finalmente te recomiendo de no colocar tanto código dentro de un bloque `try` más encima usando la muy generica `Exception` para atrapar errores. Como te diste mensaje de error te mintió - nunca fue un problema de iniciar la conexión.
Mejor sería de encapsular cada consulta en su propio bloque de `try`... `catch` para poder mandar la consulta a stdout en caso de error:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM info_XboxOne WHERE juego = ?";
ResultSet rs;
try{
    rs = execPreparedQuery(con, sql, titulo);
} catch (SqlException se){
    // puedes imprimir lo que quieres saber sobre lo que pasó
    System.out.println(String.format("Error con consulta: %s , dato %s", sql, titulo));
    se.printStackTrace();
}
```

Nunca ahorra en información en un bloque `catch`, si no sabes exactamente en que condiciones llegas adentro y estas seguro que no se necesita más datos sobre lo que pasó.

Comment: Lo he probado y me marca la linea 84, que corresponde con el código `ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM info_XboxOne WHERE juego = " + titulo);`

Answer (score 1):

Creo que esta consulta no funciona bien.

```
("SELECT * FROM info_XboxOne WHERE juego = " + titulo);
```

Lo he probado en una base de datos mía y da error. En su lugar deberías probar algo así:

```
SELECT * FROM info_XboxOne WHERE juego = ?;
```

y luego st.setString(1,titulo);

Comment: La SELECT que te da error no tiene por qué darlo. Si su tabla se llama `info_XboxOne` tu solución no le va a funcionar. Sé que intentas ayudar pero ten cuidado a la hora de dar una respuesta pues puedes ocasionarle fallos nuevos a alguien inexperto. Sería mejor que la borraras para evitarlo.

Comment: Pero es que el problema no es del nombre de la tabla. Su problema viene de la condición del WHERE. Al ser la variable titulo un String debería ir entre comillas simples y tal y como el está concatenando la consulta va a dar error. De hecho, ya ha comentado que le da error en esa linea. Para hacer esa consulta correcta debería ser asi:  "SELECT * FROM info_XboxOne WHERE juego = ' "+titulo+" ' ";   o bien, como dije, hacerlo con un  PreparedStatement

Comment: Se lo que dices y puede que sea el error, o puede ir más encaminado a que no usa la BD que cree usar como parece en otras respuestas, el caso es que si no corriges tu sentencia desde luego tiene un nuevo error porque la tabla que has puesto en tu ejemplo no existe.

Comment: Me he dado cuenta que había escrito mal el nombre de la tabla. Ya lo he editado, disculpas.

Answer (score 0):

Deberías cambiar la siguiente linea

```
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM info_XboxOne WHERE juego = " + titulo);
```

a

```
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM info_XboxOne WHERE juego = '" + titulo + "'");
```

Una vez que hayas cambiado esa linea seguirás con problemas ya que cuando estas haciendo los insert, estas dejando valores sin asignar, por ejemplo, que pasa si "game" es igual a "null"? tu query luciría de la siguiente manera:

```
INSERT INTO info_XboxOne (Juego, Tipologia, Pertenece, Nota, Descripcion_Ingles, Descripcion_Castellano, Pegi, Descripcion_Pegi, Lanzamiento) VALUES ("Estados Unidos",?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

Por lo que esto es un error de sintaxis en SQL, igualmente ocurriría para el UPDATE, recuerda asignar todos los valores de "?" en el query de lo contrario tendrás errones al ejecutar el código. Si no necesitas llenar todos los valores deberias asignarle por lo menos un String vacío.

Comment: Efectivamente esa linea me la ha mostrado como error, lo he cambiado al que me has puesto a ver cómo funciona. Por otra parte, game no será nunca "null", esa comprobación estaba antes porque tenía los enlaces a cada juego se comprobaban por cada país, pero he cogido como referencia el de Estados Unidos y todos comparten los mismos enlaces. Lo que puede pasar es que haya algún dato que no exista para ese país, en cuyo caso se asigna "-".

Answer (score -1):

Al parecer el problema es que estas usando `MariaDB` y NO `mySql`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El driver para `MariaDB` es incorrecto debe ser:

```
//private String driver ="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
private String driver ="org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver";
```

y el connection String:

```
   // private String cadenaConexion ="jdbc:mysql://localhost/XboxOne";
  private String cadenaConexion = "jdbc:mariadb://localhost/XboxOne"
```

te aconsejo revisar la [documentación de MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/about-mariadb-connector-j/)

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu comentario. No tenía ni idea de que `MaribaDB` y `MySQL` eran cosas distintas. He hecho los cambios y estoy ejecutando de nuevo el programa junto con alguna modificación arriba mencionada.

Comment: Me sigue dando error con `Mariadb`: https://s2.postimg.org/4kosd5vmx/Captura_de_pantalla_2017_02_25_a_las_23_35_52.png

Comment: Agrega que error estas obtienes?